# R: How to use ggbiplot with pcaRes object? plot PCA results of data with missing values

Tags: r, plot, pca, ggbiplot, biplot

I usually perform Principal Component Analyses with the `prcomp` function, and plot the results in a fancy way with `ggbiplot` (or otherwise just with `ggplot2` extracting `pca.obj$x`).

Like this:

```
#install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
library(ggbiplot)
data(iris)
pca.obj <- prcomp(iris[,1:4], center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE)
P <- ggbiplot(pca.obj,
         obs.scale = 1, 
         var.scale=1,
         ellipse=T,
         circle=F,
         varname.size=3,
         var.axes=T,
         groups=iris$Species, #no need for coloring, I'm making the points invisible
         alpha=0) #invisible points, I add them below
P$layers <- c(geom_point(aes(color=iris$Species), cex=5), P$layers) #add geom_point in a layer underneath (only way I have to change the size of the points in ggbiplot)
png(filename="test.png", height=600, width=600)
print(#or ggsave()
    P
)
dev.off()
```

[image: test1]

HOWEVER, now I am facing data with some amount of NAs, and I am using the `pca` wrapper function from the [pcaMethods](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/pcaMethods.html) package, applying the `nipals` method (an iterative method capable of handling small amounts of missing values).

`pca` returns an object of class `pcaRes`, and `ggbiplot` returns the following error:

```
#introduce NAs
iris$Sepal.Length[sample(1:150, 5)] <- NA
iris$Sepal.Width[sample(1:150, 5)] <- NA
iris$Petal.Length[sample(1:150, 5)] <- NA
iris$Petal.Width[sample(1:150, 5)] <- NA
#pca.obj2 <- prcomp(iris[,1:4], center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE) #cannot use prcomp with NAs
#source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
#biocLite("pcaMethods")
library(pcaMethods)
pca.obj2 <- pca(iris[,1:4], method="nipals", nPcs=3, center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE)
class(pca.obj2)
ggbiplot(pca.obj2)
```

> Error in ggbiplot(pca.obj2) :    Expected a object of class prcomp,
>   princomp, PCA, or lda

MY QUESTIONS are:

How can I apply `ggbiplot` to a `pcaRes` object?

How can I convert this object to a `prcomp` object?

Can I obtain the same kind of plot with another function instead of `ggbiplot` that accepts a `pcaRes` object?

Should I just replace the NA values with the mean of the variable and apply the `prcomp` function as usual?

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to use `str(pca.obj2)` and compare the result with the result of `prcomp`. Then try to make it compatible with `ggbiplot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, good job finding a PCA package that will handle NAs.

Since `ggbiplot` will not accept `pcaRes` objects, we can use the data obtained by the `pcaRes` and sneak it into the original `prcomp` object.

Obviously your real data will already contain the `NA` values, so we'll start with that data set and swap them out for some dummy values to allow us to run the first `prcomp` `pca`.

```
iris_na<-iris

iris_na$Sepal.Length[sample(1:150, 5)] <- NA
iris_na$Sepal.Width[sample(1:150, 5)] <- NA
iris_na$Petal.Length[sample(1:150, 5)] <- NA
iris_na$Petal.Width[sample(1:150, 5)] <- NA

iris_dummy<-iris_na

iris_dummy[is.na(iris_dummy)]<-7777 #swap out your NAs with a dummy number so prcomp will run
```

We then run the first `pca` as you did:

```
pca.obj <- prcomp(iris_dummy[,1:4], center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE)
```

There are 5 components of this object, `x` (scores), `rotation` (loadings), `sdev` (standard deviation), `center` and `scale`. Although I suspect that only the scores and the loadings are used by `ggbiplot`, we'll swap them all out just to be sure.

Looking at the scores component `pca.obj$x` shows us that four principal components have been calculated in the `prcomp` function.

`head(pca.obj$x)`

```
#           PC1        PC2         PC3         PC4
#[1,] -2.656740  0.3176722  0.03763067 -0.04122948
#[2,] -2.688275 -0.1821744  0.19912795  0.07297624
#[3,] -2.862673 -0.1447518 -0.02134749 -0.02462359
#[4,] -2.718294 -0.3189371 -0.03318459 -0.11675762
#[5,] -2.700864  0.3274887 -0.07503096 -0.11347939
#[6,] -2.252918  0.7436711 -0.14611455 -0.08218007
```

So when we run the next pca with `pcaRes`, we make sure to specify that 4 principal components are calculated using the `nPcs` argument. Here we are using the true data, which contains the `NAs`.

`pca.obj2 <- pca(iris_na[,1:4], method="nipals", nPcs=4, center=TRUE, scale.=TRUE)`

It is then just a matter of swapping out the `pcaRes` values for the `prcomp` values and passing this to `ggbiplot`

```
pca.obj$x<-pca.obj2@scores 

pca.obj$rotation<-pca.obj2@loadings 

pca.obj$sdev<-pca.obj2@sDev

pca.obj$center<-pca.obj2@center

pca.obj$scale<-pca.obj2@scale

P2 <- ggbiplot(pca.obj,
              obs.scale = 1, 
              var.scale=1,
              ellipse=T,
              circle=F,
              varname.size=3,
              var.axes=T,
              groups=iris$Species, 
              alpha=0) 
P2$layers <- c(geom_point(aes(color=iris$Species), cex=5), P2$layers)
```

[image]